# Вызов анимации в фрагменте из активити или AndroidRuntimeException

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Пытаюсь вызвать проигрывание анимации во фрагменте из активити.
Но ловлю такю ошибку:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Animators may only be run on Looper threads
```

Вот метод фрагмента, который я вызываю из активити:

```
 public void setConnect(){
        ivOk.setPivotX(ivOk.getWidth()/2);
        ivOk.setPivotY(ivOk.getHeight() / 2);
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ivOk, "scale", 0, 1);
        animator.setDuration(350);
        animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                ivOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            }
        });
        animator.start();
    }
```

Comment: Скорее всего, вы пытаетесь запустить анимацию из другого потока (не UI). К сожалению вы не показали код активити, где вызываете метод фрагмента.

Comment: Да, не из UI. Сделал вызов внутри runOnUIThread и все заработало, я так понимаю - это единственный способ?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка говорит о том, что вы запускаете анимацию не в [Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) треде.
Та, как сделали вы с runOnUIThread - это работает, потому, что UI-тред сам по себе является Looper тредом. Второй вариант - использовать [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).